# Spring Boot gradle build bootBuildImage. How to exclude test properties from image

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

In my SpringBoot project I have

```
application-prod.properties
application-test.properties
```

With the corresponding settings

I build the image using

```
./gradlew bootBuildImage
```

In the image I have both properties, so I can for example use

```
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test" -p 8080:8080 my_image_name
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod" -p 8080:8080 my_image_name
```

I would like to exclude the test properties from the image. How to do it?